# Set a button of custom color to a disabled style

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qcolor

I have a class that inherits `QWidget`. Under certain circumstances, I wish to set it disabled.

The widget has some color buttons, that are set from a list of colors:

```
void MyWidget::colorUpdate(QString color)
{
    if(!color.isEmpty())
    {
        QString foreground = (QColor(color).lightness() < 125 ? "white" : "black");
        m_colorButton->setStyleSheet("color: " + foreground + "; background-color: " + color);
    }
}
```

Calling `myWidget.setEnabled(enabledOption);` disables the widget, grays out all text and every other items in the widget - except for these color buttons.

So I am thinking of making my own action:

```
void MyWidget::setWidgetEnabled(bool enabled)
{
    this->setEnabled(enabled);
    // what else ?
}
```

How can I make my buttons - of a background color and text color that I don't know, but the button does - have that "disabled look" ?

(Note - the color update works on disabled items too - that is not really complicated though - whatever style sheet I apply on setting widget disabled can be applied in the `colorUpdate` function).

I just don't know how to apply a stylesheet with that gray shade - or possibly have a "disabled" option in the stylesheet even...
What do colors look like in "disabled" ?

Comment: Just add the custom color change bindings to your `setWidgetEnabled()`? Easy way out is to to modify color balances, for example hue and saturation. It’s your (custom) data, so you know best how it should look like when ”disabled”.

Comment: Thanks, that is the biggest question, I don't want the button to look "custom different" - just have the same washed out look as everything else. I don't know how to make colors look "disabled".

Comment: But you’ve set custom colors to that button? Why you’d expect Qt to know how your colors should look when it’s disabled?

Comment: Right - but I imagine "disabled" applies some sort of colorize or, like you said, a certain change in hue and saturation. I would like to know what that is.

Comment: Well, I’d expect the rules to change between themes, but setting custom styles explicitly overrides the defaults from the theme, so you should figure out the disabled style you want too, for your case. Decreasing saturation makes it look ”washed”, making the color darker (or grayer) makes it look disabled. Making fonts gray instead of whatever color may help too. I’m not a designer so I can’t tell you what your thing should do and SO anyway isn’t Designer as a Service...

Comment: I thought there would be some property of colors that I can apply. Decreasing saturation sounds like what I am looking for then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**To set your own style for the disable state**. 
You can set a special [style for disabled state](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-pseudo-states) in the stylesheet :

```
m_colorButton->setStyleSheet(":enabled { color: " + foreground 
                             + "; background-color: " + color 
                             + " } :disabled { color: " + disabledForeground 
                             + "; background-color: " + disabledColor + " }");
```

*edit: changed code for the widget instead of a global stylesheet.*

---

**To keep the default disabled style**. You can set your custom style only for the enabled state, then when the widget is disabled the style does not apply :

```
m_colorButton->setStyleSheet(":enabled { color: " + foreground 
                             + "; background-color: " + color + "}");
```

Comment: The style MUST apply in disabled state. I just want it to looked washed-out, as if it was disabled. The first part of the answer, I imagine I would need to subclass my button to do...? And this still does not answer the question: How can I get "disabled style" colors based on existing colors, and "disabled style text" even for black and white text. But I think I will use the comment to the question, and decrease the color saturation.

Comment: I misunderstood the question then. As said above best is probably to create your own disabled colors, adapted to your custom colors. And to answer your comment, no you don't need to subclass the button, I gave a global QSS example but you can do this directly : `m_colorButton->setStyleSheet(":enabled { color: " + foreground + "; background-color: " + color + " } :disabled { color: " + disabledForeground + "; background-color: " + disabledColor + " }");`