# QLabel with pixmap: prevent pixmap's color change in disabled state

Tags: c++, qt

How can I control the color of its pixmap in disabled label state?

For some bizarre reasons I need to have exactly the same look of the pixmap in active and disabled state (displayed logo).

The pixmap I put on a QLabel with `label->setPixmap(pm)` is always shown in a different color than the active state when the label is in disabled state.

I struggled with the stylesheet and tried `QFrame:disabled{background-color: rgba(..., ..., ..., 255);}` but the part of the label which is covered with the pixmap is always a mix with another color, which seems to come from Qt's controlling for the disabled state.

---

EDIT: It seems, Qt always mixes the pixmap color and the background color in disabled state. But Qt does not mix the colors in active state; then the pixmap color stays opaque. I need to switch off this mixing behavior of the disabled state.

Comment: Did you see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36868434/set-a-button-of-custom-color-to-a-disabled-style ? Did you try it?

Comment: @vahancho: yes, but it's about buttons, and my case is about QLabel with a set pixmap.

Comment: [This is the code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qlabel.cpp.html#1108) that draws the pixmap on a `QLabel`. If you don't need any of the `QLabel` functionalities, you could just subclass `QWidget` and draw your pixmap there. Or you can create your own `QStyle` class and reimplement `QStyle::generatedIconPixmap` and set that style to your label. Or subclass `QLabel` and reimplement the `paintEvent` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A (not so complicated) way to achieve that, is to draw the pixmap by yourself. Instead of subclassing `QLabel` and override `paintEvent`, you can install an event filter in your label and listen for `QPaintEvent`'s only.

Have the filter:

```
class Filter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Filter(): QObject(nullptr) {}
    bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event);
};
```

In its `eventFilter` method, always return false, but when you draw the pixmap:

```
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QStyle>
bool Filter::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::Paint)
    {
        QLabel * label = dynamic_cast<QLabel*>(watched);
        QPainter painter(label);

        QPixmap pixmap = label->pixmap()->scaled(label->size());        
        label->style()->drawItemPixmap(&painter, label->rect(), Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter, pixmap);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Instantiate and install the filter, something like:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
Filter * filter = new Filter();
ui->label->installEventFilter(filter);

/* don't forget to call: 

    delete filter;
  
  somewhere later */
```

In my example code, I scaled the pixmap to fit the label size and centered it both horizontally and vertically, but you can adjust all this, according to your needs.

Moreover, the same filter can be installed to more than one label, since the logic works fine for them all. More on event filtering [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters).